# Restrict user to enter date manually in text field

Tags: php, html

I use a calender with text field, i want only calender selected value is inserted on text value, other keyboard manual value is not inserted on text box.

```
<input type="text" name="date_to" value="<?php echo $date_to; ?>" placeholder="To" id="to" class="Original-datepicker" required />
```

This is my code. when i click on this text box then calender is open and selected value is insert on text value. I want here only calender selected value is used here as text value. Manual value is not inserted here.

I need to restrict user for enter date manually...

i use this jquery code for both my calender or timepicker

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
        $( "#from" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
    });

     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#onselectExample').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'h:i A','minTime': '9:00am', 'maxTime': '9:00pm', });

        $('#onselectTarget').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'h:i A','minTime': '9:00am', 'maxTime': '9:00pm', });
    });
```

i use readonly='true' like:--

" `placeholder="To" id="to" class="Original-datepicker" required readonly='true' />`

this help me in calender case

but in timepicker case i face same problem..

timepicker is open as dropdown and i select one time option.
when i use readonly then dropdown is not open..

Comment: sharing a fiddle would be helpfull in this case..

Comment: what calendar/datepicker your are using? share your code which initiating datepicker!

Comment: i use simple jquery calender class="Original-datepicker" initiate the calender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply add `readonly` attribute

```
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="date_to" value="<?php echo $date_to; ?>" placeholder="To" id="to" class="Original-datepicker" required />
```

and for timepicker, you can simply prevent to keypress event, See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cas6T/102/)

```
$('#onselectExample,#onselectTarget').keypress(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();});
});
```

Comment: yup this help me only calender case. timepicker case its not help me

Comment: if you think this is a good question then you give +1 for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Too disable keyboard input when using datepicker, You can do like this :

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - No keyboard input</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ maxDate: "-1D" }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        $("#datepicker").readonlyDatepicker(true);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```